# How to make a box in shiny app user interface

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I'm trying to have a box inside my shiny app while using the `shinythems` library :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
  navbarPage("test theme",
    tabPanel("tab1",
             mainPanel(width = 12,
                       fluidRow(
                         box(width=6,title = "title",status = "navy", solidHeader = TRUE,            
                                    dataTableOutput(outputId = "tab"))))
               
             ))
    
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output,session){
  
 output$tab = renderDataTable(mtcars)
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But it does not work as I expected !

[image]
I was hoping to get something like :

[image]

I tried the `titlePanel` as well but it did not work !

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can mix-n-match *Shiny fluidPage*, *shinythemes* & elements from *shinydashboard* just like that. For `box` to properly work it needs shinydashboard CSS and to include this you'd normally use

```r
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)
```

layout instead of `fluidPage()` / `fixedPage()` Shiny layouts.

Though..  there's [`shinyWidgets::useShinydashboard()`](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/useShinydashboard.html#ref-examples) :

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)

library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
  shinyWidgets::useShinydashboard(),
  navbarPage("test theme",
    tabPanel("tab1",
      mainPanel(width = 12,
        fluidRow(
          box(width = 12, 
            title = "title", status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE,
            dataTableOutput(outputId = "tab")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tab <- renderDataTable(mtcars)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

DT might not be the best example here as it requires some setup for responsiveness (it doesn't respect box boundaries and `box(width = 6, ...)` just draws over half of the table).

[image]

Comment: The solution just works if `status` set to `warning` or `success` !